# How could find unique objects from my object from perticular parameter in object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var links = {
    1:{source: 0, target: 1},
    2:{source: 0, target: 2},
    3:{source: 0, target: 3},
    4:{source: 0, target: 4},
    5:{source: 0, target: 1},
    6:{source: 0, target: 4}  
};
```

this is my data and I want unique objects from it by parameter: target like

```
var result= {
    1:{source: 0, target: 1},
    2:{source: 0, target: 2},
    3:{source: 0, target: 3},
    4:{source: 0, target: 4},
};
```

Comment: You should use an array instead,

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without underscore by using `Array.from` with a `Set` to remove duplicates like so:

```js
const links = [{source: 0, target: 1}, {source: 0, target: 2}, {source: 0, target: 3}, {source: 0, target: 4}, {source: 0, target: 1}, {source: 0, target: 4}]

const res = Array.from(new Set(links.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse);
console.log(res);
```

However, the above will keep elements if `target` is the same as another `target` property if another property in the object is different (ie it will remove duplicate objects).

To remove a specific duplicates based on a key from an array, you can use `.reduce`:

```js
const links = [{source: 0, target: 1}, {source: 0, target: 2}, {source: 0, target: 3}, {source: 0, target: 4}, {source: 0, target: 1}, {source: 0, target: 4}];

const res = Object.values(links.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const {target} = obj;
  acc[target] = obj;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var visited = {}
Object.keys(links).forEach((key) => {
   var val = links[key].target;
   if(!visited[val]) {
      visited[val] = true;
   } else {
      delete links[key];
   }
})
```

if you don't want to edit existing object then instead of delete push it in new object;
Note: Prefer arrays instead of object in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = {
    1: { source: 0, target: 1 },
    2: { source: 0, target: 2 },
    3: { source: 0, target: 3 },
    4: { source: 0, target: 4 },
    5: { source: 0, target: 1 },
    6: { source: 0, target: 4 }
};

links = Object.keys(links).reduce((pre, cur) => {
    pre[cur] = JSON.stringify(links[cur])
    return pre
}, []);
links = [...new Set(links)].reduce((pre, cur, idx) => {
    if (cur) {
        pre[idx] = JSON.parse(cur)
    }
    return pre
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. This matches your expected input and output.
Here, a hashable object is created and the key is generated based on `source` and `target` property. The purpose of the hashable object is to keep track if we pushed the same value before.

```js
var links = {
    1: { source: 0, target: 1 },
    2: { source: 0, target: 2 },
    3: { source: 0, target: 3 },
    4: { source: 0, target: 4 },
    5: { source: 0, target: 1 },
    6: { source: 0, target: 4 }
};

var counter = 1,
hash = {},
result = {};

var linkArray = Object.values(links);

linkArray.forEach(function(elem) {
  const key = elem.source + '' + elem.target;
  if(!hash[key]){
    hash[key] = 1;
    result[counter] = elem;
    counter++;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Hope, this will help you. Thanks!